# firebase flashlight request timed out error [30000ms]

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flashlight

I am working on indexing firebase data to elastic search with [firebase flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight). After starting the app.js (indexer) in the  library, it stops after 30000ms throwing:

`failed to index indexname/resource/ffd5517e-cab0-4bec-8989-4f6d760f18eb: Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms`
due to which most of the firebase data do not get indexed.

I have given requestTimeout parameter in app.js while initializing the elastic search

```
var esc = new ElasticSearch.Client({
  hosts: [
     {
        host: conf.ES_HOST,  // http://localhost
        port: conf.ES_PORT,  // 9200
        auth: (conf.ES_USER && conf.ES_PASS) ? conf.ES_USER + ':' + conf.ES_PASS : null
     }
  ],
  requestTimeout: 1200000  //this is in ms (20 mins)
});
```

in this case the request is always fulfilled but the indexer timeouts after 30 seconds while fulfilling the requests.

This happens while indexing dev database, which I can control by giving a heafty timeout duration, but for production data I cannot decide the timeout.

Can anybody let me know on how to handle the requestTimeout so that it does not die out while indexing the firebase data.

I have gone though 
[Elasticsearch times out on every search request until restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962107/elasticsearch-times-out-on-every-search-request-until-restart)  : this is not that relevant but I have looked into it
[Elasticsearch response into Firebase (Flashlight)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305950/elasticsearch-response-into-firebase-flashlight)
but couldn't get a related solution.